# Jira Plug-In For Collaborative Scoring / Prioritizing

Tags: jira, scoring, backlog

JIRA QUESTION!!! What's the best plug-in extension for Jira that will help multiple people collaboratively score features(Jira issues) in order to prioritize them? Any recommendations would be SUPER SUPER SUPER appreciated.

We looked into product board but it's not really meant for collaborative scoring. We want multiple people to be able to collaboratively score at the same time like Google Sheets, but just something embedded within the Jira environment.

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall a Jira Poker plugin from Spartez. They are reputable.